# I would like to dedicate my father who passed away

Tags: word-choice

I would like to dedicate my father who is passed away and I cant find the approriate word since I am not native speaker

Comment: We speak of dedicating a work **to** a person: "I would like to dedicate this dissertation to my late father."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try, ***pay your final respects***

> pay your respects
>
> to express your admiration or friendly feeling for someone.
>
> Usage notes: sometimes used in the form *pay your final respects* (to express your admiration for someone who has died.)
>
> [Cambridge Dictionary of American Idioms](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pay+respects)
>
> *I would like to pay my [final/last] respects to my father who just passed away.*

Answer (score 1):

I am very sorry for your loss. In English we do not generally dedicate a person, but rather an object or act to a person, as @StoneyB says. You are probably looking for a way to ***honor*** your father in ***remembrance*** of his good qualities.